# Limit WGET'ing by timer, how to do this?

Tags: linux, scripting, wget

Sorry for my english (i'm rus)

I save MJPEG stream from IP-camera with wget

```
wget -O 2010-01-12_01.mjpeg http://172.16.1.220:8070/video.mjpg
```

I need limit saving by hour (every hour is a another file - 2010-01-12_[XX])

What is the bast way to do it ?
1) starting and killing by cron ?
2) for .. do in script, how ?
...

thanks for answers

Answer (score 2):

You can use the timeout utility:

```
timeout 3600 wget -O `date +%Y-%m-%d_%T`.mjpeg http://172.16.1.220:8070/video.mjpg
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like this:

```
( wget ... & sleep 3600; kill %1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

sweet as bash kludge

```
wget whatever &
sleep 60 && kill $$ 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternate method to wget

```
while [ "true" ]; do 
ffmpeg -t 3600 -i http://172.16.1.220:8070/video.mjpg -vcodec mjpeg /path/to/storage/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H).mjpg
done
```

Answer (score -1):

try `curl` with the `-m` or `--max-time` option

Comment: please add a complete example to your answer